# How to deal with data dependencies in a component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a component that displays a list of **Project**. I'm fetching the data from the server in the *componentDidMount()*. In the reducer, I'm selecting the first item, setting a **currentProject** variable. I would like to display the **Tasks** associated with this **Project**. How to make sure that I have this variable set before fetching the **Tasks**?

**Projects**

```
class Projects extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.selectProject = this.selectProject.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { fetchByUserId, user } = this.props;
    fetchByUserId(user.id);
  }

  selectProject(e, project) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { select } = this.props;
    select(project.id);
  }

  render() {
    const { items } = this.props;
    return (
    <div>
      <div className="projects">
        <ul>
          {_.map(items, (project) => (
            <li key={project.id} onClick={(e) => this.selectProject(e, project)}>
              {project.title}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>    
      <div className="tasks">
          <Tasks />
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { user } = state.authentication;
  const { items, loading, error } = state.projects;
  return {
    user,
    items,
    loading,
    error
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    fetchByUserId: projectsActions.fetchByUserId,
    select: projectsActions.select
  }
)(Projects);
```

**Tasks**

```
class Tasks extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { fetchTasksByProjectId, currentProject } = this.props;
    if (currentProject) {
      fetchTasksByProjectId(currentProject.id);
    }
  }

  renderTasks(tasks) {
    return (
      <div>
        {_.map(tasks, (task) => (
          <strong>{task.name}</strong>{" "}
          {task.description}
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { currentProject, tasks } = this.props;
    if (!tasks.length) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="title">{currentProject.title}</h1>
        {this.renderTasks(tasks[currentProject.id])}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { current: currentProject } = state.projects;
  const { items: tasks } = state.tasks;
  return {
    currentProject,
    tasks
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    fetchTasksByProjectId: tasksActions.fetchByProjectId
  }
)(Tasks);
```

In **Tasks** *componentDidMount()*, I'm trying to fetch the data only if the variable is set, but my component is never rendered again. I'm missing something, but what?

Comment: You could try to make the `projectActions.fetchByUserId` action dispatch the `tasksActions.fetchByProjectId` action when it finishes getting all of the projects. This way, you're guaranteed to have the `currentProject` variable set because `tasksActions.fetchByProjectId` won't be called until it's set.

Comment: I would like to be able to call projectsActions.fetchByUserId without necessary call tasksActions.fetchByProjectId as well. I know how to chain actions in action creator, but I would like to be able to do it in the React Component. Like having an option to pass a chained action...or not.

Comment: Just added another answer, which I think (?) solves your problem. In short, conditional rendering is your friend and is less complicated than chaining different actions together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand the question slightly better now, so here's how I'd do it: instead of checking whether `currentProject` exists in the `Tasks` component, why not check for it and conditionally render `Tasks` in the `Projects` component? Something like:

```
...
<div>
  { this.props.currentProject && <Tasks /> }
</div>
...
```

This way, Tasks isn't rendered/mounted until `this.props.currentProject` is populated, making the check in `componentDidMount` redundant, and allowing you to fetch the tasks without checking.

Comment: Definitely what I was looking for! Really easy =/ Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to chain the fetchTasksByProjectId to the fetchByUserId action call.

In pseudo code:

```
getProjectByUserId
.then(projects => 
  getTasksByProjectId(projects[selectedProjectIndex])
)
.catch(error)
```

Also, remove the tasks call from your componentDidMount()

```
//projects action call
export function getProjectByUserId(user_id) {
 return async(dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
      let projects = await projectsService.getProjectByUserId(user_id);
      dispatch({ type: "FETCH_PROJECTS", projects});
      /*Notice the call to another action in the response of the first action call, fyi the getState is used to access the id of current project in your redux state*/
      dispatch(getTasksByProjectId(projects[getState.currentProject.id])); 
    }
    catch (error) {
        return error;
    }
  };
}

//Tasks action call
export function getTasksByProjectId(project_id) {
 return async(dispatch, getState) => {
   try {
     const tasksData = await projectsService.getTasksByProjectId(project_id);
     dispatch({ type: "FETCH_CURRENT_TASKS", tasksData});
   } 
   catch (error) {
     return error; 
    }
 };
}
```

A more detailed example to understand the action file better. Here the services are the files with the actual get requests. The dispatch calls are to handle the data returned from the call.

Comment: thanks, I figured out that I should chain my action dispatches. But to do that, should I tell the first action to accept a promise?

Comment: Edited the post to add a more suitable example. let me know if it helps

Comment: But what if I don't want to call the tasks action every time? I know how to chain actions like that, but I wanted to do it only if needed it, like instead of hard coding the dispatch of _getTasksByProjectId_, passing it like you first answer.